# Is it possible to run the "ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool" on a remote server?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I know how to launch the "ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool" from Visual Studio and modify the security settings in the web.config of my Web project.

However, can I use the same tool to configure a remote website (hosted in some server), without Visual Studio (just as a website?)

If it's not possible. Is there a control that I can add to my website to administer the same settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point your SQL Server connection string to your remote SQL Server, so seems you're configuring a local instance, but data are being persisted on a remote location.

You can also check this out: [Rolling Your Own Website Administration Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111539/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx)

Comment: In which file do I have to change the connection string of WSAT?

Comment: You should remove and re-add the `LocalSqlServer` connection string.